# systemd-journal-flush.service Failed with result timeout - Failed to start Flush Journal to Persistent Storage

Tags: centos, systemd, systemctl, systemd-journald, timeout

I see this on my systemctl log, the systemd-journal-flush.service fails to start with a timeout error. Server is apparently running fine though. OS is CentOS 8. Logs don't tell much about the error. If anyone could help me I appreciate.

```
#sudo systemctl start systemd-journal-flush.service
Job for systemd-journal-flush.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.


#systemctl status systemd-journal-flush.service
● systemd-journal-flush.service - Flush Journal to Persistent Storage
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-journal-flush.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Sat 2023-03-18 04:08:07 GMT; 3min 28s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-journald.service(8)
           man:journald.conf(5)
  Process: 13447 ExecStart=/usr/bin/journalctl --flush (code=killed, signal=TERM)
 Main PID: 13447 (code=killed, signal=TERM)

Mar 18 04:06:37 systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Mar 18 04:08:07 systemd[1]: systemd-journal-flush.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
Mar 18 04:08:07 systemd[1]: systemd-journal-flush.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=15/TERM
Mar 18 04:08:07 systemd[1]: systemd-journal-flush.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Mar 18 04:08:07 systemd[1]: Failed to start Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.


#journalctl -xe
Mar 18 04:06:37 systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
-- Subject: Unit systemd-journal-flush.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
--
-- Unit systemd-journal-flush.service has begun starting up.
Mar 18 04:06:37 systemd-journald[860]: Runtime journal (/run/log/journal/9b0915b205da456da00e935c8704118b) is 14.3M, max 38.3M, 23.9M free.
-- Subject: Disk space used by the journal
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
--
-- Runtime journal (/run/log/journal/9b0915b205da456da00e935c8704118b) is currently using 14.3M.
-- Maximum allowed usage is set to 38.3M.
-- Leaving at least 57.5M free (of currently available 368.6M of disk space).
-- Enforced usage limit is thus 38.3M, of which 23.9M are still available.
--
-- The limits controlling how much disk space is used by the journal may
-- be configured with SystemMaxUse=, SystemKeepFree=, SystemMaxFileSize=,
-- RuntimeMaxUse=, RuntimeKeepFree=, RuntimeMaxFileSize= settings in
-- /etc/systemd/journald.conf. See journald.conf(5) for details.
Mar 18 04:06:42 dbus-daemon[1068]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.timedate1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.timedate1.service' requested by ':1.718' (uid=0 pid=10797 comm="cockpit-bridge --privileged " label="unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023")
Mar 18 04:06:42 systemd[1]: Starting System clock and RTC settings service...
-- Subject: Unit timedatex.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
--
-- Unit timedatex.service has begun starting up.
Mar 18 04:06:42 dbus-daemon[1068]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.timedate1'
Mar 18 04:06:42 systemd[1]: Started System clock and RTC settings service.
-- Subject: Unit timedatex.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
--
-- Unit timedatex.service has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
Mar 18 04:08:07 systemd[1]: systemd-journal-flush.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
Mar 18 04:08:07 systemd[1]: systemd-journal-flush.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=15/TERM
Mar 18 04:08:07 systemd[1]: systemd-journal-flush.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `journald` daemon is not flushing to `/var/log/journal` because that directory doesn't exist, and `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` does not tell it to create that directory. Unfortunately, `journalctl --flush` waits for the flush to complete, which it never will.

The solution which worked for me was this:

1. `sudoedit /etc/systemd/journald.conf`
2. After the `[Journal]` line, add a line that says `Storage=persistent`
3. Reboot.

If you read the `journald.conf(5)` man page, you'll see this explanation for how `persistent` differs from the default `auto`:

> "auto" is similar to "persistent" but the directory `/var/log/journal`
> is not created if needed, so that its existence controls where log
> data goes.

By changing the configuration and rebooting, you're allowing `journald` to create the missing directory with the right permissions (which is, apparently, owner=root, group=systemd-journal, mode=02755, with an ACL granting explicit `r-x` access to groups adm and wheel). Of course, you could create it yourself and avoid the need to reboot.

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by a bug [fixed in systemd-239-75.el8](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2174645).

Adding the `Storage=persistent` line to /etc/systemd/journald.conf as suggested in the other comment switches to persistent logging (it writes the journal to disk instead of using non-persistent ring buffer).